# How UDP works when pass through smaller MTU

Tags: networking, udp, udpclient, mtu

I am sending 1 MB of UDP data from one system to another system through multiple routers. Both systems have 1500 MTU, and in between the two hosts I have one router with a lower MTU like 576.

So will the router (with lower MTU (576)) *fragment the UDP packet and send to the receiving host* or will it *send ICMP message(PMTU) to sending host* for further fragmentation?

Answer (score 5):

In IPv4 the router should fragment the packet unless the don't fragment bit is set. Only in the latter case the router should throw the packet away and send an ICMP fragmentation needed back. In IPv6 the router will not fragment but throw the packet away and send an ICMP6 packet too big.

Comment: Since IPv6 requires the path MTU to be at least 1280, it would never work where an MTU is 576 in the path.